# Having two fields, How can keep the maximum number of unique element 2 values, but not repeating any element1?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have some problem that we can't solve, and the related problem can be explained with the following example:

| element1 | element2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 4 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 6 |

What is needed is to filter the example table and keep the maximum number of unique element2 values, but not repeating any element1 values. For this example, some possible solutions are:

| element1 | element2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 4 |

| element1 | element2 |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| D | 5 |

| element1 | element2 |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 6 |

...

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the first solution:

```
with recursive optimized(n,saved) as (
select 0, cast('' as varchar)
union all
select n + 1,
    (
    case
        when (position(cast(element2 as varchar) in saved)= 0)
    then (
        case
            when(position(element1 in saved)= 0) then
        concat(element1, element2)
            else
    concat(saved)
        end
)
        else 
concat(saved)
    end
)
from
    optimized
join rownum on n + 1 = rn
),
rownum as(
select
    element1,
    element2,
    row_number() over() as rn
from
    example1
)
select distinct element1, element2
from 
    optimized
join example1 on concat(element1, element2)= saved;
```

This is the output:

| element1 | element2 |
| --- | --- |
| D | 4 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 1 |